# mysql DISTINCT is showing same thing twice

Tags: mysql

I have a table with more than 5k records. The field payment_mode has 3 types- A, B, C.
When I query this:
SELECT DISTINCT payment_mode from MY_TABLE it gives the below result:

```
payment_mode    
A
B
C
A
B
C

Shouldn't it be just showing:
A
B
C
```

This is resulting in a wrong report on application front.

Comment: Check for invisible characters.

Comment: when I am running this to find the difference :  SELECT [YourColumn], CAST([YourColumn] as varbinary(max)) FROM [YourTable]      it throws syntax error

Comment: I don't thing DISTINCT is what you are looking for. Try SELECT payment_mode FROM my_table GROUP BY payment_mode

Comment: There is no varbinary in mysql or square brackets - which make me suspect this is not a mysql question. If it is try cast(..as binary)

Comment: its mysql only 
SELECT payment_mode FROM my_table GROUP BY payment_mode

A A B B C C

Comment: SELECT payment_mode, CAST(payment_mode as varbinary(max)) FROM my_table   

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varbinary(max)) FROM my_table  LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: If group by gives multiple results for A you might have Spaces around it. use TRIM()

Comment: Which bit of there is no varbinary in mysql was unclear to you please see manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html for valid cast types.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT DISTINCT(payment_mode) from MY_TABLE